# Get Sum, Multiple Group By with Filter

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a table with the following columns that I am trying to create a view from in order to create a report, I need to get the sum of completed hours for a particular class but with a specific filter:

```
| PK_CLASS_DAYS_ID | FK_MAIN_ID | FK_CLASS_ID | CLASS_DAY | OUTCOME | CLASS_DATE | HOURS | 
|------------------|------------|-------------|-----------|---------|------------|-------| 
| 1                | 27452      | 137         | 1         | *15     | 2015-11-15 | 8     | 
| 2                | 27452      | 137         | 2         | *15     | 2015-11-16 | 8     | 
| 3                | 27452      | 137         | 4         | *15     | 2015-11-18 | 8     | 
| 4                | 27452      | 137         | 5         | BS15    | 2015-11-19 | 8     | 
| 5                | 27452      | 2           | 1         | *16     | 2001-01-01 | 8     | 
| 6                | 27452      | 48          | 1         | *16     | 2016-01-12 | 8     | 
| 7                | 27452      | 48          | 2         | *16     | 2016-02-27 | 4     | 
| 8                | 27452      | 2           | 1         | *17     | 2017-07-01 | 8     | 
| 9                | 27452      | 137         | 1         | *16     | 2016-07-16 | 8     |
```

I need to find the SUM of hours completed for each class (`FK_CLASS_ID`) for every student in my table (currently I have filtered it to ID 27452 for testing purposes) while applying the following filter for each class (`FK_CLASS_ID`):

- (1)`CLASS_DAY` must be distinct
- (2)`CLASS_OUTCOME` must begin with "*"
- (3)`CLASS_DATE` must be the most recent, while still having the previous two conditions. The resulting view should be as follows:

```
| PK_CLASS_DAYS_ID |  FK_MAIN_ID |  FK_CLASS_ID |  Hrs |
|------------------|-------------|--------------|------|
| 1                | 27452       | 137          | 32   |
| 2                | 27452       | 2            | 8    |
| 3                | 27452       | 48           | 12   |
```

The furthest I've gotten with trying to accomplish this, is the following select statement:

```
SELECT
t1.CLASS,
SUM(class_hours) as Hrs,
GROUP_CONCAT('D',classes_days.class_day) as DaysList,
main.FULLNAME
FROM
classes t1
INNER JOIN classes_days ON classes_days.FK_CLASS_ID = t1.CLASS_ID
INNER JOIN main ON main.PK_MAIN_ID = classes_days.FK_MAIN_ID
WHERE
main.PK_MAIN_ID = 27452
GROUP BY FK_CLASS_ID
ORDER BY CLASS
```

Comment: Can you explain what's the problem with the statement you have?

Comment: You should be careful when tagging. sql server <> mysql. I would edit the tags but there is a pending edit right now.

Comment: My current statement does not factor in the distinct CLASS_DAY column nor does it only add the most recent date if there is two rows with the same CLASS_DAY for the same FK_CLASS_ID. Also, it must only add rows that has the column OUTCOME beginning with asterisk. This is for MySQL v5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you're wanting to accomplish, you would need to filter your joins with the desired summation queries and provide the joining on the desired criteria from the retrieved recordset.

Basing it off your provided query and desired results, it should look like:

```
SELECT
`t1`.`CLASS`,
SUM(`class_hours`.`HOURS`) AS `Hrs`,
GROUP_CONCAT('D', `class_hours`.`CLASS_DAY` ORDER BY `class_hours`.`CLASS_DAY`) AS `DaysList`,
`main`.`FULLNAME`
FROM `classes` AS `t1`
INNER JOIN (
    #Filter the total hours by student, class, and day
    SELECT `class_dates`.`FK_MAIN_ID`, `class_dates`.`CLASS_DAY`, `class_dates`.`FK_CLASS_ID`, SUM(`class_dates`.`HOURS`) as `HOURS`
    FROM (
        #Filter Most Recent Days beginning with star, by most recent date
        SELECT `classes_days`.* 
        FROM `classes_days` 
        WHERE `classes_days`.`OUTCOME` LIKE '*%'
        ORDER BY `CLASS_DATE` DESC
    ) AS `class_dates`
    GROUP BY `class_dates`.`FK_MAIN_ID`, `class_dates`.`CLASS_DAY`, `class_dates`.`FK_CLASS_ID`
) AS `class_hours`
ON `class_hours`.`FK_CLASS_ID` = `t1`.`CLASS_ID`
INNER JOIN `main`
ON `main`.`PK_MAIN_ID` = `class_hours`.`FK_MAIN_ID`
GROUP BY `class_hours`.`FK_MAIN_ID`, `class_hours`.`FK_CLASS_ID`
ORDER BY `FULLNAME`, `CLASS`;
```

Resulting In:

```
|   CLASS | Hrs |    DaysList | FULLNAME |
|---------|-----|-------------|----------|
| History |   8 |          D1 |      Joe |
|    Math |  32 |    D1,D2,D4 |      Joe |
| Science |  12 |       D1,D2 |      Joe |
|    Math |  10 |       D1,D2 |     Mike |
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5828/1

*Original query of table is the top query. The subquery join example is the bottom query result. Removed the `PK_MAIN_ID` criteria to show it working against multiple entries*

Do keep in mind that MySQL `GROUP BY` + `ORDER BY` does not always yield the desired results, and should be filtered using a subquery, which is demonstrated in the join subquery in order to get the most recent dates that begin with *.

Comment: Wow! That statement looks loaded, its going to take me some time to read and understand it. Once I do I will apply it to my situation and report back the results. Thank you for your reply, very much appreciated.

Comment: I tweaked your original statement to get my desired result, instead of select all records in the  <em>#Filter Most Recent Days beginning with star, by most recent date</em> Section. Instead of selecting all i selected specific columns and used DISTINCT. Works as expected, thank you. Although I feel I am going to have to break up this statement into different views in order for it to work as I need it to.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that all your fields in the statement have Single Quotes, is there a reason for it? Does it make a difference?

Comment: There are backticks `\`` wrapping column and table definitions, single quotes `'` wrapping values and the added `AS` keyword for aliases, Usage of them is best practice to prevent issues with reserved keywords, functions, readability and cross-platform/application/language programming. For example `SELECT * FROM interval WHERE NULL = 'a'` vs `SELECT * FROM \`interval\` WHERE \`NULL\` = 'a'` The former query would attempt to typecast the criteria as an interval, and compare the value of `NULL` to `'a'` - the later would query the table `interval` and column named `NULL`.